# WPF - binding Inside a collection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, datagrid

I'm looking to bind a specific element of a list.

```
Public Class itemCATIA

    Property l As New List(Of itemCATIAProperties) 'the list

   Sub New(d)
    For Each item As Parameter In pCATIA.UserRefProperties
                Dim myP As New itemCATIAProperties(item.Name, 
                 item.ValueAsString)
                l.Add(myP)  'the list
     Next
    end sub

end class

Public Class itemCATIAProperties

    Property Name As String
    Property Value As String

    Sub New(item As String, _value As String)
        Dim s() As String = Strings.Split(item, "\")
        Name = s(UBound(s))
        Value = _value
    End Sub
End Class
```

and below my tests to bind the correct value inside a dynamically created column :

```
 Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim c As New DataGridTextColumn
        c.Header = "MASS"
        c.Binding = New Binding("l[Name='MASS'].Value") 'does not work
        c.Binding = New Binding("l[0].Value") 'does not return the good index of my list l. i want index=c.header
        MaDataGrid.Columns.Add(c)
    End Sub
```

Is there a method to retrieve the value whose index is the column header ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your code, as written and posted, doesn't have any way to access an item by string (it's a List which is supports positional access).  You can't do something in WPF that you couldn't do in code.  If you were to have a string-based indexer, then maybe you could write a binding that would work the way you want.

Comment: Hi @Craig, thanks for your reply. Like you see below i resolved my question with something not very beautifull. Tanks to your comment, i found this : stackoverflow.com/questions/49058487/… Do you refer to this ? Do you think i can add a function like this in my binding ?
i tried this binding and seems to not working : 
   c.Binding = New Binding("l[l.FindIndex(Function(x As String) x.Contains(" & c.Header & "))].Value")

I will keep searching in this way hoping to find something, thanks

Comment: I wouldn't expect to be able to embed VB code in WPF and have that work.

Comment: My suggestion, rather, was that if you have a property indexing by string on the VB side (on the data context object type), then you could do a WPF binding on that property.

Answer (score 1):

Well i resolved with something not very beautiful.. if someone get a best solution, i take :)

i replaced in the sub new() :

```
    Dim l_ As New List(Of itemCATIAProperties)
    For Each item As Parameter In pCATIA.UserRefProperties
        Dim myP As New itemCATIAProperties(item.Name, item.ValueAsString)
        l_.Add(myP)
    Next

    For i = 1 To 30
        l.Add(Nothing)
    Next
    For Each item In l_
        Select Case item.Name
            Case "MATERIAL"
                l(0) = item
            Case "OBSERVATIONS"
                l(1) = item
            Case "LENGTH"
                l(2) = item
            Case "LENGTH"
                l(3) = item
            Case "THICKNESS/DIAMETER"
                l(5) = item
            Case "MASS"
                l(5) = item
            Case "SUPPLIER"
                l(6) = item
            Case "REF"
                l(7) = item
            Case "TTS"
                l(8) = item
            Case "SYM"
                l(9) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Marquage"
                l(10) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Traitement"
                l(11) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Protection"
                l(12) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Dim_Brutes"
                l(13) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Masse"
                l(14) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Matiere"
                l(15) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Designation"
                l(16) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Indice"
                l(17) = item
            Case "NomPuls_Planche"
                l(18) = item
            Case "DETAIL NUMBER"
                l(19) = item
            Case "STOCK SIZE"
                l(20) = item
        End Select
    Next
```